# Passing Querystring value into View Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have a parent child situation with for example my user class and my userwork child class (Entity framework scaffolded classes). i used the controller wizard to scaffold CRUD methods and views. it scaffolded two  Create method's, the Get and the httpPost methods.

In a normal scenario i would want to be passing in the user's id into the get so that it would be passed into the model which is being populated in html.beginform() section and then it would subsequently be passed into thepost.

I am unsure what is the correct method to do this?  I have modified the Get as below

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
 {
     this.ViewData.Add("id", id);
     return View();
 }
```

and the Create.shtml as below

```
@model UserWork

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    int id = (int)ViewData["id"];
}

<h2>Create</h2>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm(routeValues:new {user_id = @id})) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Userwork</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user_id)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user_id)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user_id)
        </div>
......
```

(i left the scaffolded user_id fields as editable so i could test seeing them prepopulated when the form loads) which the form loads it doesnt have my id value in the fields, Is this the correct method of achieving this?

Cheers
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my initial question raised several other questions about my understanding of MVC and routing.  i established that if i pass one parameter as an integer to the route in the form

```
http://mydomain/controller/myaction/123
```

if my action method is in the form

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
        {}
```

everything is cool but if its in the form

```
 public ActionResult Create(int user_id)
        {}
```

then i was getting an exception that the required parameter user_id wasnt populated. 
I  added an additional mapping as below and this seems to be correctly populating the view.

```
routes.MapRoute("Create", "{controller}/Create/{user_id}",new {action = "Create"});
```

I decided not to instantiate the model and pass it into the view as using the route above it passes the userid into the model's user_id field correctly.

Cheers
Tim

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to pass the Id in ViewData, but I would use ViewBag instead since you're using MVC3. It's basically a dynamic based wrapper for ViewData that get's rid of the need for the casting

controller:

```
this.ViewBag.UserId = userId;
```

You can then access the ViewBag property as `ViewBag.UserId` in your view

Comment: ok ive changed it to use viewbag, but why is this not being populated in the model and thus visible when i see the page within the textbox?

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing any model to your view. That's wrong for me. Your view is strongly typed to the `UserWork` model, so the controller action should normally pass an instance of that model to the view instead of using any ViewData or ViewBag:

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    var model = new UserWork();
    model.user_id = id;
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view:

```
@model UserWork

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm() {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Userwork</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user_id)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user_id)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user_id)
        </div>
......
```

Notice also that in the `Html.BeginForm` you don't need to repass the `user_id` because you have a corresponding editor template for this field inside the form. But usually there shouldn't be a text input field so that the user can modify the id of the entity that is being edited. In this case you could use the route data or a hidden field.

Comment: if i debug it i can see that the model is null. but in the httppost create method they have values additionally even though i have specified that the user_id field should be set to this value, when i inspect the object in the httppost i can see that the id field has this value. my id field is the primary key for this userwork table and the foreign key is the user_id which although i have specified in the routevalue isnt being passed in.

Comment: if i remove change as you suggested the user_id is correctly present still in the model being received into the get and thus present in the httppost Create when i debug it, but curiously the id value i passed into the page is also present in the id column. I will remove the textfield for edit for these primary and foriegn key values but they are present for the test only.   I did have my get specified initially as public ActionResult Create(int user_id)
{}  but the routing didn't find this value. if i want to populate a different named parameter in the route do i need to add a different route?

Answer (score 1):

I had a same type of problem with parent->child relation. But I resolved it by creating a below route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "route_name",
                "Parents/{parent_id}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "list", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new { parent_id= @"\d+" }
            );
```

in your case it will become-

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "User_Route",
                "Users/{user_id}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "list", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new { user_id= @"\d+" }
            );
```

and example urls for UserWorke-

```
(siteurl)/Users/1/UserWork/list
(siteurl)/Users/1/UserWork/New
(siteurl)/Users/1/UserWork/Edit/1
```

so forth....

with this route its easy to navigate from one action to another action because you dont need to pass user_id again and again on redirect. and also give a clear picture in URL about what you are navigating.